# Set UITableViewCell background color using a CALayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, calayer, quartz-graphics

On iOS, I am adding a CALayer to a UITableViewCell's layer.  This is my first time using CALayer, and it is simply supposed to change the background color of the table cell.  My goal is (1) to learn how to use CALayer, and (2) to test using Instruments whether the drawing is faster than my current implementation, which slows down on CGContextFillRect.

([Technical Q&A QA1708](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1708/_index.html) was the catalyst for all this.)

## Current Implementation (works)

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)r
{
    UIColor *myColor = [self someColor];
    [myColor set];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextFillRect(context, r);  // draw the background color
    // now draw everything else
    // [...]

}
```

## Attempted New Implementation (doesn't work)

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation MyCell {
    CALayer *backgroundLayer;
}

- (id) initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    if (self) {
        // [...other stuff here too]
        backgroundLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
        [[self layer] addSublayer:backgroundLayer];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)r {
    backgroundLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, r.size.width, r.size.height);
    [backgroundLayer setBackgroundColor:[self someColor]];
    // now draw everything else
    // [...]
}
```

I see the correct colors, but none of the other drawing (I'm assuming the custom drawing ends up *behind* my new layer).

If I remove the `backgroundLayer.frame = ...` line, all of my other drawing is still there, but on a black background.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try with `insertSublayer:atIndex:0` instead of `addSublayer:`. This puts the layer at the bottom of the sublayers array. The OS uses the layer `zPosition` and the relative position in the sublayers array to determine which layer is visible and which is occluded.

Comment: @Aaron Brager Why are you using a `CALayer` here? What do you wish to do with it that you can't already do on `UIView`?

Comment: @DanielMartín That didn't work.  At indices 0 and 1, I just get a black background; 2 and higher I don't see my drawing.

Comment: @JacobRelkin I'll test out your answer suggestion tomorrow morning.  The reason I'm trying this is that my cells are actually much more complex than in this question, and scrolling slows significantly with many subviews.  Drawing everything by hand in `drawRect` helped a lot, but there are a few lines that the time profiler is highlighting as inefficient.  The Q&A I linked to suggested CALayers and only 1 UIView might be better, so I'm building my cells with them and comparing time profiler / core animation FPS results in Instruments.

Comment: @AaronBrager Another contributor to your issues could be stemming from your assignment of view-level properties such as `backgroundColor` *within* your `-drawRect:` implementation. These likely have their setters overridden in their respective implementations which mark the view as dirty and thereby runs it through another (unnecessary) drawing cycle. So, your `-drawRect:` probably gets called `2^N` times. YMMV, but I think that it's a very good practice to **NOT** be doing any view-level property mutation in your `-drawRect:` implementation.

Comment: @JacobRelkin In my current implementation, I'm determining the background color separately.  I moved the drawing of the background color to the `tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you're getting unexpected behavior is because of `UITableViewCell`'s relatively complex view hierarchy:

```
- UITableViewCell
   - contentView
   - backgroundView
   - selectedBackgroundView
```

Whenever you define custom drawing routines in a `UITableViewCell`, you should be doing so within the `contentView` hierarchy. This involves subclassing `UIView`, overriding `-drawRect:`, and adding it as a subview into the `contentView`.

The reason why your background color was being ignored in your example was due to your adding your `CALayer` as a sublayer of the `UITableViewCell`'s layer. This is obscured by the `UITableViewCell`'s `contentView`.

However, for some reason, you wish to use a `CALayer` here. I'd like to understand why as it doesn't have anything that a `UIView` doesn't have. You can set the `backgroundColor` on your `contentView` instead of doing this roundabout set of things.

Here's an example using `CALayer` as you requested:

```
@implementation JRTableViewCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
   self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
   if(self) {
      [self addCustomLayerToContentView];
   }
   return self;
}

- (void)addCustomLayerToContentView {
   CALayer *layer = [[CALayer alloc] initWithFrame:[self bounds]];  
   [layer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor blueColor] cgColor]]; //use whatever color you wish.

   [self.contentView.layer addSublayer:layer];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks.  This change shaved a couple seconds off my `drawRect` function's execution time, and now my table is scrolling at around 56-58 frames per second instead of 40-45 FPS.

Comment: There isn't an `initWithFrame:` method and `setBackgroundColor:` takes a `CGColorRef`, not a `UIColor`.